# Download file from web and then save with a save file dialog box?

Tags: c#, download, save

How can I download a file, then save it to wherever I want? I am using Windows Form, Web Application.

I know I can download it with this code:

```
WebClient wClient = new WebClient();
wClient.DownloadFile("WebLinkHere", @"C:\File.txt");
```

But I want a save box like when you press CTRL+S.

Comment: are you using winforms\wpf? is that a web application? Some full scenario would be appreciated.

Comment: I am using Windows Form yes, web application!

Answer (score 5):

You can use [SaveFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. Example:

```
var dialog = new SaveFileDialog();
dialog.Filter = "Archive (*.rar)|*.rar";

var result = dialog.ShowDialog(); //shows save file dialog
if(result == DialogResult.OK)
{
    Console.WriteLine ("writing to: " + dialog.FileName); //prints the file to save

    var wClient = new WebClient();
    wClient.DownloadFile("WebLinkHere", dialog.FileName);
}
```

will show next dialog and if you search for next folder
[image]

application will print:

```
writing to: C:\Temp\archiveName.rar
```

Comment: How about if i want to save it ONLY as .rar?

Comment: Just did it. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2):

This will work and open the file download popup.

```
String FileName = "FileName.xls";
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", FileName));
            Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter htmlTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);
            Response.Write(stringWriter.ToString());
            Response.End();
```