# .NET Prompt a Save As dialog on download

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am trying the following, as seen here on SO:

```
       System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;

        response.ClearContent();
                            response.Clear();
                            response.ContentType = "video/mp4";
                            response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "video/mp4");
                            response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename + "; ");
         response.WriteFile(sourcepath + filename);
   response.End();
```

But no dialog opens and I have no idea where it saves the file.

Thanks

Comment: What browser is it? Does this happen on other browsers too?

Comment: @shahkalpesh Only tried in Chrome

Comment: The code you show should not open a dialog, it will just save to the sourcepath specified by you in the code, if you want a dialog to pop up i think you need something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19972266/download-file-from-web-and-then-save-with-a-save-file-dialog-box

Comment: BTW this code is not gonna always open a save dialog box. To do so, replace `"video/mp4"` with `"application/octet-stream"`.

Comment: you maybe have a bug and there is nothing send - or if you use firefox and this is a video (mp4) its save it automatically - check your browser settings

Comment: Armando - if the browser is going to save a file, which is what this code is attempting to do, it *should* be prompting rather than trusting the server to specify where the file should be stored. I can't think of any modern browser which would trust a server-supplied path.

Comment: The `filename` might have the wrong [encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93551/how-to-encode-the-filename-parameter-of-content-disposition-header-in-http), so check whether this is the case.

Comment: Surely it just follows the usual download protocol that the browser provides. For example in most browsers it saves to "downloads" and shows it in a ribbon at the bottom of the browser. Its definitely a browser specific thing which you won't be able to change from server side code.

Comment: I'm afraid nothing is working..

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two options:

1. Changing the Content/Type to "application/octet-stream" (as said by @Xaqron).
2. Using the [HTML5 download attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp) if you are using an anchor tag or something like that in your HTML to redirect to the download.

Comment: 2. Never tell people everything you know? (Sorry, wrong punchline :-|)