# Downloading a file from url that triggers save dialog

Tags: c#

I am trying to automate downloading of some files by automating Internet Exporer.

The code works in that it can click the download button (iframe inside an iframe) which then triggers a save dialog.

To get around the save dialog popping up in IE, I have inspected the download button and retrieved the address, which is:

`"https://.../Shared/RepositoryFileServer.ashx?fileId=7129415&Type=Attachment"`

There are a couple of points to note about this url:

1. If I run this url inside the "automated" explorer window, the save dialog displays and I can download the file
2. If I run this url in a new explorer window, it doesn't work, it's as if it uses cookies or a session (I don't have the knowledge to know about what happens in the background).

Running this code:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadFile(link, fullPath);
```

creates a file, but is corrupted and I suspect it is because of point 2 above i.e. this isn't using the current session.

My question then is, if I could somehow access the same session, would DownloadFile work on this link? I ask because this link isn't a "direct" link to the file, something like `https://.../Shared/Repository/file.xlsx` because it is being generated in the background.

For my automation I am using `InternetExplorerMedium`. I won't paste the code here as this part works great.

One caveat to this is that I am building this in a large financial institution, and practically air walled off, so I cannot download any extension such as selenium etc, I just have to use stock .net 4.7.

Any direction or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19972266/download-file-from-web-and-then-save-with-a-save-file-dialog-box

Comment: First make HTTP GET request the first link and examine the result, it should probably returning a response with the correct file link with any of the http redirect responses. Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11749676/download-file-through-code-that-has-a-redirect for more information.